# How do i stop an image from moving by the edges of the screen in Pygame?

Tags: pygame

I just started with pygame and want to make a minigame with a weapon (pixelart). I made it move by arrow keys on the keyboard, but the image moves by the edges, how do I block it from going further than the edges? The dimensions of my "character" is 220x116 pixels

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
from sys import exit

background_image = 'mario bg.png'
weapon = 'scar.png'

pygame.init()
SCREEN_SIZE = (800, 800)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(SCREEN_SIZE, 0, 32)
pygame.display.set_caption("SCAR MINIGAME")
background = pygame.image.load(background_image).convert()
player = pygame.image.load(weapon).convert_alpha()


x, y = 150, 353
MOVE_RIGHT = x=+10
MOVE_LEFT = x=-10
MOVE_UP = y=-10
MOVE_DOWN = y=+10
direction = 0

while True:

for event in pygame.event.get():

    if event.type == QUIT:
        exit()

    if event.type == KEYDOWN:
        if event.key == K_LEFT:
            MOVE_LEFT = False
        elif event.key == K_RIGHT:
            MOVE_RIGHT = False
        elif event.key == K_DOWN:
            MOVE_DOWN = False
        elif event.key == K_UP:
            MOVE_UP = False

    elif event.type == KEYUP:
        if event.key == K_LEFT:
            MOVE_LEFT = True
        elif event.key == K_RIGHT:
            MOVE_RIGHT = True
        elif event.key == K_UP:
            MOVE_UP = True
        elif event.key == K_DOWN:
            MOVE_DOWN = True


if(direction == MOVE_LEFT):
    x-=0.4
elif(direction == MOVE_RIGHT):
    x+=0.4
elif(direction == MOVE_UP):
    y-=0.4
elif(direction == MOVE_DOWN):
    y+=0.4

screen.blit(background, (0, 0))
screen.blit(player, (x, y))
pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. 
Try to be a little more specefic, when you paste in your code. It's easier to evaluate, where the problem is happening :)

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to check the co-ordinates of the `player`, and restrict them to on-screen, or make them wrap around.

I find it's *handy* to keep the window dimensions in global variables, and use these in setup functions, and later calculations:

```
WINDOW_WIDTH=800
WINDOW_HEIGHT=800
screen = pygame.display.set_mode( (WINDOW_WIDTH,WINDOW_HEIGHT) , 0, 32)
```

So when you update the position of `player`:

```
# Check player is on-screen
if (player.x < 0):
    player.x = 0
elif (player.x > WINDOW_WIDTH):
    player.x = WINDOW_WIDTH
if (player.y < 0):
    player.y = 0
elif (player.y > WINDOW_HEIGHT):
    player.y = WINDOW_HEIGHT

screen.blit(background, (0, 0))
screen.blit(player, (x, y))
```

It would be a more complete answer to include the width of the sprite for the `> WINDOW_WIDTH-sprite_width` check so it still shows on-screen, but that exercise is left for the reader.

So back to the code.  The new function `keepPointOnScreen()` takes a co-ordinate and checks that it's on the screen, modifying it if not.  Calling this function each time the player position is updated keeps the sprite on-screen.  Since the sprite is painted from the left-side, it's still possible to "hide" the sprite on the right & bottom.  To fix this, the keeper function needs to take into account the bitmap width.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
from sys import exit

background_image = 'mario bg.png'
weapon = 'scar.png'

# Keep these as variables for checking later on the code
WINDOW_WIDTH=800
WINDOW_HEIGHT=800

# Setup the window
pygame.init()
SCREEN_SIZE = (WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT)
screen      = pygame.display.set_mode(SCREEN_SIZE, 0, 32)
pygame.display.set_caption("SCAR MINIGAME")

# load images & set starting positions
background    = pygame.image.load(background_image).convert()
player        = pygame.image.load(weapon).convert_alpha()
player_width  = player.get_width()
player_height = player.get_height()
print("Player image is [%u x %u]" % (player_width, player_height))

x, y       = 150, 353
direction  = 0
clock      = pygame.time.Clock()


###
### Given a co-ordinate, ensure the co-ordinate is inside the screen 
### bounds.  If it's outside the screen area, reduce it to inside,
### or wrap it to the other side
###
### The code uses the WINDOW_WIDTH and WINDOW_HEIGHT globals,
### Assuming the window is 0 to WIDTH-1 in pixels, and similiarly for height
####
def keepPointOnScreen(x,y, bm_width, bm_height, wrap=False):
    global WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT

    if ( wrap == False ):
        # Block on the edges of the screen (no wrapping)
        if ( x < 0 ):
            x = 0
        elif ( x >= WINDOW_WIDTH-bm_width ):
            x = WINDOW_WIDTH-bm_width-1
        if ( y < 0 ):
            y = 0
        elif ( y >= WINDOW_HEIGHT-bm_height ):
            y = WINDOW_HEIGHT-bm_height-1
    else:
        # Wrap-around from side to side and top to bottom
        if ( x < 0 ):
            x = WINDOW_WIDTH-bm_width-1
        elif ( x >= WINDOW_WIDTH-bm_width ):
            x = 0
        if ( y < 0 ):
            y = WINDOW_HEIGHT-bm_height-1
        elif ( y >= WINDOW_HEIGHT-bm_width ):
            y = 0
    return x, y


while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if ( event.type == QUIT ):
            exit()

    # Movement keys 
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if ( keys[pygame.K_LEFT] ):
        x -= 1
    elif ( keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] ):
        x += 1
    elif ( keys[pygame.K_UP] ):
        y -= 1
    elif ( keys[pygame.K_DOWN] ):
        y += 1

    # make sure the point is still on-screen
    x,y = keepPointOnScreen( x, y, player_width, player_height )

    # re-paint the window
    screen.blit(background, (0, 0))
    screen.blit(player, (x, y))
    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(60) # no more than 60 FPS
```

Comment: Hello, could you please send the entire code right? I didn't really understand, sorry. I changed the dimensions to 1920x1080